# hl-line-mode emacs color change

Tags: colors, emacs, line, text-cursor

Emacs' hl-line-mode is just what i need but i would like to change it's horrible yellow color, anyone know how can i do that?

Answer (score 60):

I use `(set-face-background hl-line-face "gray13")`.

here's what it looks like with a black background.

[image]

Very subtle.  Mostly I notice it when moving the cursor, which is what I wanted.

If you want to see a display of all the various colors, try `(list-colors-display)`.  It will show a list of colors in a new buffer.

**EDIT**: heh heh, since I am getting upvoted for pretty pictures,
here it is "live":

[image]

(ps: that animated gif was produced with the [Cropper tool](http://cropper.codeplex.com) and the [AnimatedGif plugin](http://cropperplugins.codeplex.com).)

Comment: Do not be seduced by the pretty pictures! Revel in the text-only goodness, just over there (*points*) (although the `hl-line-face` variable does looks like appropriate indirection for `'hl-line`)

Comment: @phils - I think I read somewhere that `hl-line-face` was the preferred way to get to the face.  I think.

Comment: Yeah, I would say the fact that it exists is probably sufficient evidence of that :) It seems highly unlikely that it would ever make a difference, mind, but I've changed my own config accordingly.

Comment: You probably made it an after advice because having the `(set-face-background 'hl-line "gray13")` on top level results in an `Invalid face` error, but when you have it after the hl-line-mode has been loaded, then it works just fine.

Comment: Thanks for `M-x list-colors-display` :D

Answer (score 13):

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `customize-group` <kbd>RET</kbd> `hl-line` <kbd>RET</kbd>

and modify "Hl Line face".

Alternatively, you could use (for example):

`(set-face-background 'hl-line "#333333")`

edit: cheeso's answer would be the more robust approach for that second version.

Answer (score 2):

On top of all the nice answers, you can also do it with `use-package` as follows:

```
(use-package hl-line                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
  :custom-face                                                                                                                                                   
  (hl-line ((t (:background "#aaaaaa")))))
```

`hl-line` is the *customizible* face added in **Emacs 22** according to [the author of `hl-line+`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/hl-line+.el/).